# explicit (holomorphic) map revealing blow-up as a connected sum with $\overline{\mathbb{CP}}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to understand the statement that a blow-up of a complex manifold $M$ at a point $p$ is equivalent to the connected sum of $M$ with $\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}$ and, being a physicist, I need the *explicit* map between charts. I have looked at a number of sources, but found [Broens'](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ecaval101/homepage/Students_files/JPSBroens.pdf) thesis particularly useful. Using this one may construct a transition function from the blow-up of $M$, $\tilde{M}$, to $\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}$. The problem I have is that it doesn't look very holomorphic.

**the set-up**

> If $M$ has co-ordinates $z'$ with $z'(p)=0$, then the blow-up $\tilde{M}$ is given by the set of points
>
> $\{ (z', [w]) \in \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{CP^{n-1}} \;|\; z'_iw_j=z'_jw_i\}$
>
> Now define a map $\psi:\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}\to\tilde{M}$ by
>
> $\psi(\overline{Z}_0:Z_1:Z_2…:Z_n)=(Z_0Z/|Z|^2,\;[Z])$
>
> where $Z=(Z_1,Z_2,…Z_n)\neq0$. The inverse of this map is, I think,
>
> $\psi^{-1}(z',[z'])=(|z'|^2:z'_1:z'_2:…z'_n)$
>
> A ball in $\mathbb{CP^n}$ about the point $q$ with co-ordinates $(1:0:0…:0)$ is defined by the set
>
> $B_\epsilon=\{ (\overline {Z}_0:Z)\;|\;\;|Z|/|Z_0|\;\leq\;1/\epsilon  \}$
>
> which is then removed to give the set $V_\epsilon$ that will be glued on
>
> $V_\epsilon=\{ (\overline {Z}_0:Z)\;|\;\;|Z|/|Z_0|\;>\;1/\epsilon  \}$
>
> the image of which is
>
> $\psi(V_\epsilon)=\{ (Z_0Z/|Z|^2,\;[Z])\;|\;\;|Z|/|Z_0|\;>\;1/\epsilon \}$
>
> so if we define the co-ordinates on $M$ to be $z'=Z_0Z/|Z|^2$ we find the set of points
>
> $U_\epsilon=\psi(V_\epsilon)=\{  (z',[z'])\;|\;\;|z'|<\epsilon \}$
>
> now make the annulus for the connected sum by constructing $U_\delta$, $\delta<\epsilon$, and the corresponding annulus on $V_\epsilon$.
>
> So, given a point on the annulus in $M$, $z'\in U_\epsilon-U_\delta$, we get a point
>
> $(|z'|^2:z'_1:z'_2:…z'_n)=(1:z'_1/|z'|^2:z'_2/|z'|^2:…z'_n/|z'|^2)$.
>
> on $\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}$ with inhomogeneous co-ordinates $z'_i/|z|^2$

**the problem**
There's a good chance that I have totally misunderstood something, but if we take $\zeta_i$ to be the inhomogeneous co-ordinates on $\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}$, then the above relates the charts of $M$ and $\overline{\mathbb{CP^n}}$ via

$\zeta_i=z'_i/|z|^2$

which is not holomorphic. Given that, for example, the del Pezzo surfaces are blow-ups, and also complex manifolds, I would have expected a holomorphic map between charts.

Answer (score 3):

What is important about the differential-topological construction you ask about is that the blowup $\operatorname{Bl}_pM$ of a complex $n$-manifold $M$ is only (orientation-preservingly) *diffeomorphic* to $M \# \overline{\mathbf{CP}^n}$, and not in fact holomorphic to it, since in particular $\overline{\mathbf{CP}^n}$ isn't a complex manifold, and so the connected sum construction is not performed in the holomorphic category.

For clarification, I also recommend the discussion in §2.5 in Daniel Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry;* in particular, the proof of Prop. 2.5.8 seems relevant, and writes down the explicit map you do. Another reference is János Kollár's "[The structure of algebraic threefolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-02/S0273-0979-1987-15548-0/)," in §9.2 (although it is very concise).